# How to keep "MODAL" with form open on Managed bean validation?

Tags: jsf

Im working with JSF and botstrap.
I have a created a pop with with values to submit. 
On clicking the submit button im calling a managedBean function, in which i have done some validations like:-

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( "password:newUserPassword2", new FacesMessage("Password should contain a minimum of 8 characters"));

But when i click the submit button pop up is getting closed and when i take the popup again the messages are displayed.

How do i prevent the pop up from getting closed ?

Comment: So, you're immediately closing the popup during onclick before you get the chance to check if there are any validation errors?

Comment: When you say "popup" you mean [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)?

Comment: @MarceloBarros: Modal or not should not make a difference

Comment: What BalusC indirectly says is: create an [mcve] See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info/

Comment: @Marcelo Barros : Yes i meant "modal" im new to bootstrap

Comment: @BalusC : Yes it was getting closed before even if there was validation errors, it should not behave like that right

Answer (score 1):

After much research found a solution.
I used f:ajax to prevent the pop up from closing the pop up like

```
<h:commandButton id="submitPassword" action="#{managedBean.managedBeanFunction}" value="Submit">
                        <f:ajax execute="formId" render="formId" />
                    </h:commandButton>
```

In the managedBeanFunction we will set a flag to true (if all the validations are passed) that can be accessed from JSF.
In the modal section we will write a script segment after checking the flag

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="messages" rendered="#{managedBean.managedBeanFlag == 'true'}">
                <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                    // <![CDATA[
                           $('#closeButtonId').click();
                    // ]]>
                </script>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

So that if the flag is not set the script function wont be called so the pop up won't get closed

Comment: Cleaner is `rendered="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}"`.

Comment: Also, I asked if it was [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) because there is a specific javascript to close that: `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`